# Puppet exec with command mkdir -p does not fail but does not create folder

Tags: linux, puppet

I'm running this simple puppet code on Ubuntu 14.04 machines, to create folders according to a comma-separated list of paths:

```
define local_dirs ($comma_separated_dirs) {
    $folders = split($comma_separated_dirs, ',')

    exec { $folders:
       command => "mkdir -p ${name} && chmod 0777 ${name}"
    }
}
```

This resource definition is used as follows (in this case - just a single folder, no commas, other modules do need this "split" logic):

```
local_dirs { 'create-dir': 
   comma_separated_dirs => "/data/disk1"
}
```

When I run it, I see the following log line, indicating that the `exec` command was actually executed:

```
Notice: /Stage[main]/My_module/Local_dirs[create-dir]/Exec[/data/disk1]/returns: executed successfully
```

However, the folder was never created, running `ls -la /data` shows there's no such folder.

Some more facts worth noting:

- Puppet runs as root so it's not likely a permission issue
- Puppet version is 3.7.2

Please advise on what could be the issue here, or - if there are other ways to create an arbitrary number of arbitrarily-deep folder structures using Puppet - I'll gladly replace the `exec` command with anything equivalent. I'm not using puppet's `file` resource due to it's inability to automatically create the necessary parent directories (see [here](http://www.puppetcookbook.com/posts/creating-a-directory-tree.html))

**EDIT**: I'm specifically interested in a way that would spare me any coding of each folder as an array of folders following the hierarchy from root (e.g. `['/data', '/data/disk1', '/data/disk1/user1']`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the wrong expectation for the value of the `$name` variable.  You are assuming that when you use it in a resource declaration ...

> ```
> exec { $folders:
>    command => "mkdir -p ${name} && chmod 0777 ${name}"
> }
> ```

... that it represents the name of the resource being declared.  This is not the case.  It means the same thing inside that declaration as it does outside: the name / title of the instance of the defined type in which the declaration is being evaluated (the `local_dirs` instance, whose name is apparently `'create-dirs'`).  The `mkdir` is therefore creating a directory of that name in whatever Puppet's working directory happens to be.

You could solve the problem by interposing another level of defined type to wrap your `Exec`.  If you're willing to enable the future parser, however, then the forward-looking direction would be to use the new `each()` function instead of an array title to declare your multiple `Exec` resources.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using an exec, use puppets file resource. First make an array of the directories you want to create and then use the array as the the file resource title.

```
$folders = [ '/example', '/example/folder2', '/example/folder2/folder3' ]

file { "$folders" :
  ensure => directory,
  owner  => 'root',
  group  => 'root',
  mode   =>  '0777',
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I should rephrase the question to make this clearer - I know I can use `file` and list the directories in the path to get this done, but that's exactly what I'm trying to prevent, since I have many modules using this `local_dirs` defined resource, with possibly many folders to create and a rather deep hierarchy for each one of them, so these lists will be long and error-prone. I'm looking for a way to hide this detail from the various modules using `local_dirs` resource.

Comment: You could put the array values for $folder in hiera and then do a hiera lookup whenever you needed the directory tree.